# C++ fiile writer does not write characters that I give it

Tags: c++, file-writing

I'm currently working on a project for my Computer Organization class, and my professor decided to throw us headlong into a C++ project with no prior class time or experience besides bitwise operators and memory pointers. The goal of the project is to create a program that can compress or decompress files using Run Length Encoding, and we were given a framework of code to work with. I'm currently trying to write the Encode function, and this is what I have so far. Keep in mind, I have absolutely no prior experience in C or C++.

```
void compress( char* data, int count, FILE* outfile )
{
// TODO: compress the data instead of just writing it out to the file
char currentChar = data[0];
int charCount;
charCount = 0;

for (int i=0; i<count; ++i)
{
   if(data[i] == currentChar)
   {
       charCount++;
   }
   else if(data[i] != currentChar)
   {
      if(charCount > 9)
      {
           while(charCount > 9)
           {
               putc(currentChar, outfile); // write the current char to the file
               putc(9, outfile); // write 9 to the file
               charCount -= 9;
           }
           putc( currentChar, outfile ); // write the current char to the file
           putc( charCount, outfile); // write the number of currentChar to the file
       }
       else
       {
           putc( currentChar, outfile ); // write the current char to the file
           putc( charCount, outfile); // write the number of currentChar to the file
       }

       // reset the currentChar and charCount variables
       currentChar = data[i];
       charCount = 1;
      }

   }
}
```

The output this code gives is as follows:
x       x(unknown character)y(unknown character)

When it should be:
x9x1y4z3

What exactly am I doing wrong here? As far as my (extremely limited) knowledge goes, this should be correct. But again, I am completely new to C++ (my only other coding experience is in Python and Java).

**EDIT:** Ok, the numbers are writing correctly. The output is now: x9x1y4, which is almost correct. Bot now the compression code is still ignoring the three Z's I have at the end of the test file. I would run it through the debugging suite built into Eclipse, but for some reason it says the test file doesn't exist when I run it in debug mode.

Comment: Both Python and Java have well-developed concepts of ASCII codes, and the differences between bytes and characters. You are writing bytes 1 through 9, for the length count in the output, while you should be writing characters `'1'` through `'9'`.

Comment: This doesn't quite look like C++... Are you sure you're using C++ and not C?

Comment: According to the project documentation, the skeleton code provided should work with both languages.

Comment: Is char count a byte or an ASCII character?, The code for '1' in ASCII is not 1 in binary.

Comment: It exists as an integer to keep track of how many of a specific character there are, and now as an ASCII character as well for the purpose of writing that number to the output file at the recommendation of Sam V.

Comment: would help to add calls to [fflush](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fflush/) and [fclose](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fclose/) to just to make sure all the data is written out and the file is properly closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the 3 z's not being counted: your code only outputs data while processing a character. After all characters have been processed by your for loop, you need to dump the currentChar and charCount again.

Comment: You mean outside of the for loop?

Comment: Yes, at the end of the function.

Comment: That didn't seem to do anything; the output is still the same: x9x1y4

Comment: Replace lines 42 and 43 with a copy of 25-27. Then tell me why you needed to do that.

Comment: Oooooooh, I get it now. There were no other characters that the code would have recognized as different, so they weren't being written to the file. It seems like a bit of a stupid mistake to make, but I am fighting a head cold/possible flu right now, so i'm not exactly on the top of my game at the moment. Either way, thank you very much! Now I just have to reverse all of this in the decompression method.

Comment: Decompression's a lot easier. for(int i=0; i<count; i+=2) { for (int j=0; j<data[i+1]; j++) putc(data[i], outfile); }

Comment: I tried that and it does work, but it prints out way too many of each character (I counted 106 x's, 52 y's, and 51 z's).

Comment: Right, whoops. j<data[i+1]-'0'

Comment: Because it was using the ASCII character value instead of the integer equivalent, and appending -'0' to the end converts it from a char to an int (which I actually worked out on my own. as Ralph Wiggum would say, "I'm Learnding!"). It's working beautifully now!

Comment: Almost: a char is just an integer in the range -128 to +127, where as an int is an integer in the range -2-billion-ish to +2-billion-ish. The data types aren't what matter here, but the meaning of the numbers. 0 represents the number 0, whereas '0' represents the ASCII value of the keyboard character 0. It just so happens that ASCII uses sequential codes in the order you'd expect for the characters 0 through 9, so subtracting '0' is a quick-n-dirty way of converting from ASCII codes for numerals to the integer values we humans expect those symbols to represent.

Comment: Fun fact: single quotes around a character tell the compiler to substitute the numerical value of the ASCII code for that character. Double quotes around a character tell the compiler to allocate a string containing a single character, and replace the quoted value with a pointer to that string. So if you used double quotes, and convinced it to actually compile instead of just yelling at you for mixing types, you'd get some really odd results that probably would change each time you ran the program.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write a number to the file you could do something like

```
putc (charCount + 48, fp)
```

This will only work for integers 0-9. For larger numbers you will need to get each digit and add 48 to it.

Though from looking at your code, charCount variable will always be 1. I think the last line of the code might be

```
charCount += 1
```

Comment: That line was intentional, it resets the charCount variable after the character and it's corresponding number are written to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is:

```
putc('0' + charCount, outfile);
```

or

```
putc('0' + 9, outfile);
```